# Serialize form in a "hash format"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jeditable

In the documentation of [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) for the submitdata param (a parameter to include some extra params in the ajax request) it is said:

> (Mixed) submitdata: Extra parameters
>   when submitting content. Can be either
>   a hash or function returning a hash.
>
> ```
>  $(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php";,
>      {    
>          submitdata : {foo: "bar"}; 
>  });
>
>  $(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php";,
>      {    
>          submitdata : function(value, settings) {
>              return {foo: "bar"};    
>      } 
>  });
> ```

So I need to include in the submitData some params which I recover from the serialization of a form:

```
<form id="myForm">
     <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="myValue1"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="myValue2"/>
</form>
```

so when I prepare the submitdata I do:

```
submitdata : function(value, settings){
    return $("#myForm").serializeArray();
}
```

The problem is that serialize the form in this way results in a format like :

```
[Object { name="param1", value="myValue1"}, Object { name="param2", value="myValue2"}]
```

but jeditable doesn't understand it and it sends in the request

```
0[name] param1
0[value]    myValue1
1[name] param2
1[value]    myValue2
```

I have tried with serialize() function but it doesn't understand it either because Jeditable requires something like:

```
{param1: "value1" , param2: "value2"}
```

Is there any way to serialize the form in the jeditable required format or a quick way to change the format after the serialization?

Thanks.

Comment: NOTICE: When submitting as hash, info about order of form elements is lost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can solve it building an object from the serialized array, though I don't know if it would be the best way to do this.

```
submitdata : function(value, settings){
    var reformat = function(array){
        var obj = {};
        for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            var a = array[i];
            var name = a.name;
            var value = a.value;
            obj[name] = value;
        }
        return obj;
    };
    return reformat($("#myForm").serializeArray());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution given by Javi can match most cases except if you have inputs with names like "inputname[key]". You will get a javascript key {"inputname[key]": value} except of {"inputname": {"key": value} }. I suggest to use the jquery plugin jquery.serialize-hash.

https://github.com/sdrdis/jquery.serialize-hash